# Getting the locale time that is not depending on client browser

Tags: javascript

I want to get the locale time from ISO format that is not depending on local browser.
For example, I want to get the date at `ko-KR` though the browser opened in the other time zone(for example, in en-US).

The ISO string I have is `2020-10-22T00:00:00.000Z` and if I use `new Date` to it like

```js
new Date('2020-10-22T00:00:00.000Z');
```

it returns the date `2020-10-21 16:00:00 GMT-0800`.
But I want to get date in Korea like `2020-10-22 09:00:00 GMT+0900`.

The `toLocaleString` method returns string value. But I want the date object to certain locale.

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried something like `var koreaTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Seoul"});`

Comment: I'd stop recommending momentjs @ThomasSablik since its author considers it "done" and "legacy" :p

Comment: You can add an offset with e.g. `new Date('2020-10-22T00:00:00.000-0400');` But the question looks like a misunderstanding. The timestamp is stored as UTC. It's only converted for the output. The date object won't change. _"Creates a JavaScript Date instance that represents a single moment in time in a platform-independent format. Date objects contain a Number that represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"The toLocaleString method returns string value. But I want the date object to certain locale.*

That's not possible. The timestamp is stored as UTC. It's only converted for the output. The date object won't change.

> Creates a JavaScript Date instance that represents a single moment in time in a platform-independent format. Date objects contain a Number that represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Answer (score 0):

you can use `moment-timezone` to get the time as per the specific timezone.

```js
let date= moment()

let dateAsPerTimeZone = moment.tz(date,'Asia/Seoul');

console.log(dateAsPerTimeZone.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As you can read in the comments moment is legacy and shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

So, I make a function to handle this problem. The point is the [`getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset). Following is my code and the return value and function process can be different depending on your needs.

```js
const ko_offset = -540 * 60 * 1000; // it is the Asia/Seoul time zone offset in milliseconds

/**
 * Input : any locale date object
 * Output : translated input date object to Asia/Seoul timezone date object
*/
const toKoreaTime = date => {
  const d = typeof date === 'string' ? new Date(date) : date;
  let kd;
  if (d.getTimezoneOffset() === ko_offset) {
    kd = d;
  } else {
    kd = new Date(d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000) - ko_offset);
  }
  const Y = kd.getFullYear(), M = kd.getMonth() + 1, D = kd.getDate(), h = kd.getHours(), m = kd.getMinutes(), s = kd.getSeconds();

  return { Y, M, D, h, m, s };
};
```

It can be used to get the certain timezone date time for any timezone date. For example, if I want to know the Korea date time in the US

```js
const usDate = new Date(); // I'm use it in the US. (UTC -8)
const koDate = toKoreaTime(usDate); // return Korea date and time. (UTC +9)
```